C++ Meson build: How to select another compiler
I am using Meson for building C++ project and need to set compiler priority to clang instead of default gcc when it avaible. How to do that in meson.build file? Is it possible without additional meson setup args?
P.S. if this not possible, how to do the same with Cmake?
Tried to use meson setup --native-file nativefile.ini ./build command to set clang, but if system does not have clang it fails (and also reqiures to manually pass native file to meson). Same with CXX=clang++ meson setup  ./build, that is manual, I need autodetect. How to just use meson setup ./build for this to make it system-independent?

Are you sure you want to select alternate compilers passively?  I'd rather know if my desired compiler isn't available and to fail loud and hard.  And you could just write a simple wrapper script to do the check and invoke meson or cmake with the right arguments based on whether clang is available.

@StephenNewell wrapper is good idea, but it will fail with another OS, so it requires to create wrapper for each OS shell

@SupremeMachine That's basically just 2 scripts, one for Windows, one For Unix-y systems. I agree that what you are asking for seems like it violates the principle of least astonishment - if I the user have set g++ as my default c++ compiler, and you the library writer have some magic in your build system that overrides this when you find I also have clang installed, I would be rather surprised. (If you use a shell script for it, at least I know basically all bets are off about what to expect).

@SirNate so the only way is to manually implement simplest things that the entire build system is not capable of? That is sad

@SupremeMachine I found the answer, see below. I sympathize with you, and have my own frustrations with meson (globbing, subprojects, end syntax, custom_target oddities, etc.). In this case, I initially disagreed with your take, but given meson is just searching it's own hard-coded lists I have actually come around to your position (with caveat that users should still be able to override the default).

Presently Meson is not capable of specifying the default compilers (at least in meson.build). There is an issue for it here. Perhaps one day they will add such a feature.
Edit, while old (2013), I think CMake has the  same limitation:

By default, [cmake] searches for a list of known compiler names:
cc, gcc, cl, bcc, xlc, clang
In that order, in PATH.
If you set the CC (or CXX respectively) environment variable, it will use this
compiler.

